# Android Device Access Denied (ERR_ADRESS_UNREACHABLE) to PC's localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp, localhost

I've an Android app which interact to PC in local network (via Wi-Fi). My local website and databases on XAMPP server. There is no problem, i can access the MySQL or PHP files like as http://192.168.1.2/mylocalwebsite/index.php

But sometimes Android device can not access the website and Android browser or Chrome say ERR_ADRESS_UNREACHABLE. After waiting about 5 or 10 minutes, it will access and i can do my processes.

This will be local network project and Android device must be accessed to PC via Wi-Fi. I can not afford these 10 minutes. What can i do?

Actually I want to learn why i take ERR_ADRESS_UNREACHABLE error sometimes? Because the app and database running normally but only sometimes it occur. Also when Android devices can not access the page, i can access it by another PC and it works normally.

Thanks!